# Generate Getters and setters without underscore (not prefix/suffix) + eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, getter-setter

My variable is

```
private String category_code = null;
```

My getter and setter is generated as

```
public String getCategory_code() {
        return category_code;
    }
    public void setCategory_code(String category_code) {
        this.category_code = category_code;
    }
```

Is it possible to generate

```
public String getCategorycode() {
        return category_code;
    }
    public void setCategorycode(String categorycode) {
        this.category_code = category_code;
    }
```

I checked Properties-->Code Style-->Fields but that is only for prefix and suffix.

Or should I just rename my variables as m_categoryCode? and get my output as follows?

```
public String getCategoryCode() {
        return m_categoryCode;
    }
    public void setCategoryCode(String categoryCode) {
        m_categoryCode = categoryCode;
    }
```

Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java code tends to follow the camelCaseStyle, not the c_underscore_style.  Following the existing standards will generally help you in a variety of ways (you will be able to better read others' code and others will be able to better read your code, where "others" are other developers in the same language).  also, the tooling for the language tends to work better (case in point).

Comment: right so declaring the variable as categoryCode is the right way.thanks

Comment: [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 3):

The names of the getter and setter methods are derived from the field name. If you use a prefix or suffix for fields (e.g. fValue, _value, val_m), you can specify the suffixes and prefixes in the Code Style preference page (Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style).

reference at [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_codetemp.htm)